# How can you use a private gitlab container registry to pull an image in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, docker-desktop

I have a private docker registry hosted on gitlab and I would like to use this repository to pull images for my local kubernetes cluster:

```
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   68m
```

K8s is on `v1.22.5` and is a single-node cluster that comes 'out of the box' with Docker Desktop. I have already built and deployed an image to the gitlab container registry `registry.gitlab.com`. What I have done already:

1. Executed the command `docker login -u <username> -p <password> registry.gitlab.com`
2. Modified the `~/.docker/config.json` file to the following:

   ```
   {
       "auths": {
           "registry.gitlab.com": {}
       },
       "credsStore": "osxkeychain"
   }
   ```
3. Created and deployed a secret to the cluster with the file:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Secret
   metadata:
     name: registry-key
   data:
     .dockerconfigjson: <base-64-encoded-.config.json-file>
   type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
   ```
4. Deployed an app with the following file:

   ```
   apiVersion: apps/v1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     name: test-deployment 
     labels:
       app: test-app
   spec:
     replicas: 1
     selector:
       matchLabels:
         app: test-app
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           app: test-app
       spec:
         imagePullSecrets:
         - name: registry-key
         containers:
         - name: test-app
           image: registry.gitlab.com/<image-name>:latest
           imagePullPolicy: Always
           ports:
           - containerPort: 80
   ```

---

The deployment is created successfully but upon inspection of the pod (`kubectl describe pod`) I find the following events:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  21s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/test-deployment-87b5747b5-xdsl9 to docker-desktop
  Normal   BackOff    19s               kubelet            Back-off pulling image "registry.gitlab.com/<image-name>:latest"
  Warning  Failed     19s               kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    7s (x2 over 20s)  kubelet            Pulling image "registry.gitlab.com/<image-name>:latest"
  Warning  Failed     7s (x2 over 19s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/<image-name>:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Head "https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/<image-name>/manifests/latest": denied: access forbidden
  Warning  Failed     7s (x2 over 19s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
```

---

Please provide any information that might be causing these errors.

Comment: If you read the Message section on the second to last `Warning`it states: `.. denied: access forbidden`. Can you verify that the credentials are correct ?

Comment: Yep I've triple checked the credentials when logging into gitlab

Comment: The reason may be you configured your `~/.docker/config.json` to use `osxkeychain`. You should have generated the secret with default `~/.docker/config.json` after `docker login` command run. More info at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: Hi johngould9487, did you manage to solve your issue with the instructions from the above comment?

Comment: Piotr I just tried this and no such luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by editing the default `config.json` produced by `$ docker login`:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.gitlab.com": {}
    },
    "credsStore": "osxkeychain"
}
```

becomes

```
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.gitlab.com": {
            "auth":"<access-token-in-plain-text>"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks Bala for suggesting this in the comments. I realise storing the access token in plain text in the file may not be secure but this can be changed to use a path if needed.

I also created the secret as per OzzieFZI's suggestion:

```
$ kubectl create secret docker-registry registry-key \
  --docker-server=registry.gitlab.com \
  --docker-username=<username> \
  --docker-password="$(cat /path/to/token.txt)"
```

Comment: Nice that you could solve your issue. Please don´t forget to mark your answer as accepted so other people who face this issue can find it easy.

Answer (score 3):

What password do you use?

Confirm if you are using a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) with read/write access to the container registry. Your username should be the gitlab username.
I would suggest creating the docker registry secret using kubectl and a txt file with the token as the content, this way you do not have to encode the dockerconfigjson yourself. Here is an example.

```sh
$ kubectl create secret docker-registry registry-key \
  --docker-server=registry.gitlab.com \
  --docker-username=<username> \
  --docker-password="$(cat /path/to/token.txt)"
```

See [documentation on the command here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#docker-config-secrets)

Comment: Thanks for the input here OzzieFZI - I tried this and also changed to default `config.json` as described in my own answer below

Comment: Happy to help! The change to the docker config makes sense as well

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for rolling this out again so late, but I keep getting the

```
Error: ErrImagePull
```

with additional info from `kubectl describe pod` that says `failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden`.

I tried the answers aboth and they do not lead to a working state. :(

Pushing to GitLab Registry after the build works.
I tried different personal access tokens with different rights assigned to, but I keep getting this error...